# Сделать дублирование строк в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Я мало разбираюсь в БД. Возможно вопрос будет глупый (прошу прощения).
**Нужно продублировать имеющиеся строки.** 
Подскажите как это сделать? (в гугле не нашел ответа XD) 
Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Берете нужную запись, собираете с нее нужные данные, делаете новый INSERT, если у id стоит AUTO_INCREMENT, то вот вам и новая запись

Comment: а чем прелесть префиксов с именем таблицы для всех полей, кто нибудь может объяснить?

Comment: @teran  может автор еще из тех времен, когда в php небыло namespace'ов и клас объявляли как App_Models_Product_Photo_Item

Comment: @ВадимАлександру я тоже знаком с пхп с тех времен, когда неймспейсов не было ) но что-то мне не приходилось из-за этого каким либо образом уродовать БД.

Comment: @teran Почему уродовать? Программист имеет право не следовать общепринятым нормам\правилам\спецификациям в найменованиях. Главное, чтобы было комфортно работать ему или команде.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру потому что дублирование наименований напоминает дублирование кода.

Comment: @teran Я не сторонник даного стиля найменований, но и не имею ничего против этого. Вам так же советую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для условной таблицы `id, x, y, z`, где `id` это первичный ключ со значением `auto_increment` используйте insert-select

```
 insert into t
 select * from t;
```

Если вдруг ключ надо генерировать, то каким нибудь таким образом:

```
 SET @i = (select max(id) from t);
 insert into t
 select (@i := @i+1) as id, x, y, z
 from t;
```

для более новых версий mysql вместо переменных - `row_number()`